# Force element to scroll when it is slightly off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I need an element to scroll into the screen when it is partially out of it. I already have a function that is detecting whether or not it is within the viewport, but I would like to bring the element completely into the viewport using its size. Think of it as a square element which is half way in the viewport, I would like to scroll in a way that will bring that element completely in.

This may be off to the side or above or beneath the current viewport. How do I scroll the element into the viewport when it is detected to be out?

Here is the current code:

```
const $target = $(evt.target) // this is the current target which will be tested whether or not is outside of the viewport
if (isOutsideOfViewport($target)) {
      $target.scrollToBringTargetCompletelyToViewport() // how to make something like this work?
    }
```

Edit: to show in more details what I am trying to do, I have drawn the following diagram.

As you can see, the `target` is slightly outside of the viewport. The objective is to bring the target completely in the viewport.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

This would happen no matter where the `target` is on the screen, I just want to scroll just enough for it to be completely within the viewport.

Comment: Might want to provide a bit more clarity on what you really want to achieve. Are you looking to only add scroll bars, then autoscroll to center the 'square'? What if the square is too big to fit in the given viewport? Are you wanting to then re-size the 'square' to fit within the viewport? Resize only, no scrollbars?

Comment: there is no worry about the square being too big to fit into the viewport, it has already been taken care of in unrelated parts of the app. I simply want scroll in a manner that will completely incorporate the target if it is only half way in the viewport. I drew a diagram and included some more explanations in the OP.